# What does PHPUnit's @ticket annotation do?

Tags: php, annotations, phpunit

I've been trying to find out what the `@ticket` annotation is in PHPUnit:

```
/**
*  @ticket
*  @return bool
*/
public function annotationTest()
{
    return true;
}
```

I would like to use it for linking the function to a ticket in our ticketing software, but I'm afraid that there might be a different purpose intended for it.

There is an entry in the docs ([link](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.ticket)), but it has no content. I've been trying to find out more by searching online, although I can't seem to find an answer to it. It must have a purpose, I assume?

What is the `@ticket` annotation for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used by the [`phpunit/phpunit-ticketlistener-jira`](https://github.com/phpunit/phpunit-ticketlistener-jira) package, which allows your tests to interact with Jira's API. The most obvious use case (to me at least) would be to automatically re-open a ticket when a test failed.

It's actually been removed from PHPUnit 6 (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/c9f8fe11fb459e51d37fcf629e0450307b19c362), but is still functional as of V5.

It would also be possible to write a custom test listener that used similar logic, if you wanted to integrate it with another task tracker/etc. https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners

Answer (score 0):

@ticket holds the ticket number or ticket ID.

It indicates that a test addresses the issue described in ticket T1234